# Why is `NaN` a possible value for type `Int` in Elm?

Tags: elm

I recently started learning Elm. When I saw the `Int` type I assumed it was something like Haskell's `Int`, which is (I think) a machine integer.

But I was surprised to see this:

```
> Result.withDefault 0 <| String.toInt "-"
NaN : Int
```

`NaN` is a floating point concept which seems like it shouldn't apply to integers. It seems like this might be leaking in from JS, which would imply that `Int` is represented as a JS `Number`.

Is that the case? Why was this design decision made, and where can I go to learn about it?

(Also, two minor questions:

- Why isn't `NaN` a valid literal?
- How do I check to ensure my `Int` value isn't a `NaN`? The function `isNaN` is of type `Float -> Bool` http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Basics#isNaN

)

Comment: It seems to be fixed in 0.19

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NaN` isn't a valid `Int` value. It's a bug in the `elm-lang/core` package which has [since been fixed on master](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/pull/834), but hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1):

Answering second minor question (that's horrible it's still not outdated) `NaN` seems to be the only `x` such that `x /= x`

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to check for NaNs from within an Elm app?

Comment: Do you mean `isNaN` function for floats? For glitched integers you may use `isNaNInt x = x /= x`

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming some context because of the question, but yes: for Int. Thanks. Also, I didn't realize [that comparison is out of the IEEE NAN spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN) and not just a JavaScript quirk. Thanks!